# Automate Microsoft Outlook from C++

Tags: c++, mfc, outlook-addin

i want to develop an outlook add in in c++ to get some information like Subject, To, CC, and attachments , for that i am referring one link i.e http://www.olivierlanglois.net/Outlook_Automation_with_cpp_2.html#Usingthecode2 . and i also downloaded source code from this link but while building on my machine( visual studio 2008) i am getting one error i.e
fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'mfc71.lib' so please go through that link and help .

Answer (score 1):

You're using Visual Studio 2008. MFC 7.1 is "outdated" for you. The version you've got (and you should use) is 9.0. As such you'll have to try to link to `mfc90.lib` instead. I'm not sure whether further code adjustments are needed, just be prepared the code won't necessarily work out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import MSO.dll, VB6EXT.olb and MSOUTL.olb. They're in the office installation directory.

If you want an add-in, you have a template in visual studio in "other project types"->"Extensibility"->"Shared Add-in".

There you can choose a template for outlook add-in in C++. Notice that there is no difference between the application you choose to make add-in, it just tells visual studio to which application they should execute during debug, and to which application they should register the add-in for you.

Once you create and add-in template you can get an IDispatch* to the outlook application object. The application object is declared in MSOUTL.olb.

Hope it helps! :-)